# How to dynamic cancel the row groups in ag-grid

Tags: angular, aggregate-functions, ag-grid, sidebar

everyone , I enable the sidebar for ag-grid , and the columns can drag as a group column in the listing view , but I have multiple listing view , if I switch to other listing views , the row group is still there , is there any api can call to cancel all the row groups ? just like click the X in the row groups

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the grouping using the `columnApi` method `removeRowGroupColumn`, if you know the column.

Or you can remove all groupings using `getRowGroupColumns` and `removeRowGroupColumn`.

API DOCS:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/column-api/#reference-rowGroups-removeRowGroupColumn